# problem with "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc"

Tags: beamer, input-encodings

Using this preamble.tex:

```
\documentclass[bookmarks = true]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[magyar]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\date{2024}

\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip = 0pt \rightskip = 0pt plus 0cm} 

\setbeamercolor{color1}{bg=blue!60!black,fg=white}

\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}
       \frametitle{Tartalomjegyzék}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

and main body tex file:

```
\include{Preamble}

\title{20. Mátrixok sajátértékei, sajátvektorai}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{20.1. Lineáris transzformációk a $\mathbb{K}^n$ téren}

\begin{frame}[t, shrink = 23]{Lineáris transzformációk}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=true, rounded=true]{color1}
Egy $\varphi: \mathbb{K}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{K}^n$ függvényt a $\mathbb{K}^n$ tér egy lineáris transzformációjának nevezünk, ha
\begin{itemize}
  \item $\varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\qquad (x,y\in\mathbb{K}^n)$
    \item $\varphi(\lambda x) = \lambda\varphi(x)\qquad (x\in\mathbb{K}^n,\quad \lambda\in \mathbb{K})$
\end{itemize}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t, shrink = 23]{Lineáris transzformációk példái: tükrözés}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{1.png}
\end{figure}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

does not work, written the Error: Option class for package inputenc

Comment: You have two `inputenc` lines in `Preamble.tex`, remove the `latin1` line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your query since it does not really relate to Hungarian being used in the document.

Comment: Unrelated but do use \include but \input to input  the preamble